# Via Nginx Search Console Validation

Tags: nginx

I am a booking.com affiliate partner. I can redirect requests to booking.com with redirection. Now, I want to follow my site on google search console. For this reason, I would like to validate my site with google validation html file. I have already uploaded on my folder however it can be not found.

I am sharing my nginx configuration. Thank you in advance.

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name  www.example.com;
    if ($request_uri ~ .*.html.*) {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /home/example/google707f2904060d9180.html;
    }
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.booking.com/index.ru.html?aid=345793 redirect;
```

Comment: This sort of rewrite generally should be avoided. Use `location`s and `try_files` instead. See also [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) to learn quite a lot about writing a good nginx configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location / {
    return 301 https://www.booking.com...;
}

location = /google...html {
    try_files /google707f2904060d9180.html =404;
}
```

All other requests except the ones matching the exact path on the latter `location` block will be redirected here. The second block will serve the file.

Comment: i have tried, it gives 404 error.

Comment: You need to use path relative to your `root` directory in the `try_files` part.

Comment: That is, if your `root` is `/home/example`, then you need to use the version I edited above.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. i noticed, If request and file is same,  i don't need "try_files" command.